# Android - Number of extra arguments in bundle for activity/fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, arguments, bundle

Is it ok to send as many number of primitive data as you want in a `Bundle`/`Intent` while creating a new activity or fragment? Are there any caveats with regard to the number of arguments that could be passed using bundle?

Everytime I add a functionality to an existing activity or a fragment, If it simplifies the problem, I just add another primitive data type in the bundle and handle it inside. I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar post on the google groups answered by an Android Framework engineer claiming 1MB https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion also see similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552514/is-there-some-limits-in-android-bundle) post.