# Failed Binder Transaction when putting in HashMap in Android

Tags: java, android

I got the `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` error when putting a scaled `Bitmap` as `Base64` `String` into a `HashMap` and sending the map as Intent to called `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
    byte[] bytes = params[0];
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);
    int imgHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imgWidth = options.outWidth;
    if (imgHeight > 1920) imgHeight = 1024;
    if (imgWidth > 1080) imgWidth = 768;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 8;

    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,options), imgWidth, imgHeight, false);
    Items.put("image", base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(image));
```

And here is the `onClick` method that finish this `Activity`.

```
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

            returnIntent.putExtra("Map", Items);
            returnIntent.putExtra("returncode", SAVE_CODE);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
```

Some Information:

`Items = HashMap<String,String>`

If I set the line `Items.put("image", base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(image));` in comments, everything works.

What could be the problem?

I hope someone can help me.

Kind Regards!

Comment: How are you sending the Hashmap using intent? can you post the code?

Comment: The code is in the `onClick` method. It's the line `returnIntent.putExtra("Map", Items);`

Comment: Maybe that's where you are doing wrong!

Comment: May be this is the cause: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27934095/1531054

Answer (score 2):

There's a 1 MB size limit on the bundle you can send in intents. You should probably implement some global caching mechanism for your app and send the images cache id in the bundle. This is mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

Comment: Can you give me some hint how I can do this?

Comment: For starters, your could implement an LRU cache as suggested here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Have a single instance of this memory cache and keep it in your Application object. If the image you are trying to pass was downloaded from the internet - you could use it's url as an id in the cache. then simply send the url in the bundle

Comment: Can I send the LruCache via Intent to other Activities? Where can I read something about bundle? I want to get more Informations about that so something like this won't happen again. Thank you!

Comment: you dont need to send LruCache via intent just pass the image url in intent and use the same LurCache class to download the image it will return image from local cache files.

Answer (score 2):

I had come with the same issue a few weeks back. so i stored the bitmap in phone file system and passed the file path to the intent. On the other hand i just retrieved the file. You might have to use async task while writing to the bitmap to file system.