# What is the limit when passing data between fragments when using Navigation Components?

Tags: android, fragment, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to pass some data between fragments using a shared ViewModel. As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) states:

> For example, you should pass a key to retrieve an object rather than passing the object itself, as the total space for all saved states is limited on Android.

What is this limitation? In my use-case, I'm passing two objects, one with four fields and the other with only two, is this reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is reasonable, you basically pass a Bundle of arguments, which is limited to 500Kb - 1Mb, check this answer: [Is there some limits in android' bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552514/is-there-some-limits-in-android-bundle/27934095#27934095)